# Given local DateTime and lat/lon, how to determine a timezone and offset in NodeJs?

Tags: c#, node.js, postgresql, timezone-offset, iana

In the past I implemented C# library which, **given local DateTime and lat/lon**, allowed to **determine a timezone and offset**.

I did the following:

- downloaded shapefiles from efele.net/maps/tz
- imported them into SQL Server
- used them to get tzid from lat/lon

[Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) C# library was used to get all necessary information about timezone, offset, and DST.
It returns:

- Offset in minutes
- UTC DateTime
- Olson/IANA Timezone name
- Windows Timezone name
- bool IsDST

Now I need to reproduce this library in NodeJs + PostgreSQL. Is the suggested way of doing it:

- Import http://efele.net/maps/tz shapefiles to PostgreSQL
- Use Moment TimeZone library in NodeJs similar to how I used Noda Time in C#

Are there known pitfalls, difficulties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you need some actualized shapefile to map all [timezones by geo coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates).

You can use a module like [`geo-tz`](https://github.com/evansiroky/node-geo-tz) that natively support `moment-timezone` library. Or a more lightweight one like [`tz-lookup`](https://github.com/darkskyapp/tz-lookup).

Comment: Dario,
In  geo-tz .tzMoment(lat, lon, [dateTime])   dateTime parameter is a *local* dateTime, correct?  Looks like geo-tz already implemented what I was going to implement! Wow! I couldn't find such ready to use C# library 3 years ago, so I implemented my own with a big help of @MattJohnson

Comment: Yes, "(...) If dateTime is provided, `moment-timezone` will be set to the time provided according to the timezone found".